# Modifying column values after assign() r

Tags: r

I want to read multiple files into multiple data.frames:

```
files <- list.files("my directory)
for(i in seq_along(files))  
{
   name <- paste0("split_", i)

   assign(name, fread(paste0(path, files[i]), 
                      header = FALSE,
                      sep = "\t",
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   setnames(get(tname), colnames(get(tname)), clnames)
}
```

The above works fine and creates data.frames split_1, split_2, ...

My question is how do I modify a column in the created data.frames? For simplicity, let's assume I want to fill a column with 1s.

```
get(name)$COL_NAME <- 1
```

gives the following error:

```
could not find function "get<-"
```

How can it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: May be `assign(name, '[[<-'(get(name), 'COL_NAME', value=1))` in the loop.  Not tested without a reproducible example

Comment: Have you tried `assign(get(paste0(name, "$COL_NAME")), 1)`?

Comment: @akrun your solution worked! If you post it as an answer I'll give you the points ... Thanks!

Comment: @Carlos Thanks posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
assign(name, '[[<-'(get(name), 'COL_NAME', value=1))
```

within the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a temporary variable and then reassign the temporary variable to the named data.frame, e.g.,

```
v = get(name)
v[,COL_NAME] = 1
assign(name, v)
```